# How to check which SysRq functions are enabled?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, bitmaps, sysrq

The file `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` contains a single number, such as:

- `1` (enable all SysRq commands),
- `0` (disable all),
- or a base-10 positive integer which functions as a binary bitmask, enabling a subset of functions.

Could someone please tell me which SysRq functions are allowed/disallowed when the bitmask is set to `438`?

---

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
438
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

These are the available SysRq functions:

```
0 - disable every SysRq function.
1 - enable every SysRq function.
2 - enable control of console logging level
4 - enable control of keyboard (SAK, unraw)
8 - enable debugging dumps of processes etc.
16 - enable sync command
32 - enable remount read-only
64 - enable signalling of processes (term, kill, oom-kill)
128 - allow reboot/poweroff
256 - allow nicing of all RT tasks
```

`438` = `2 + 4 + 16 + 32 + 128 + 256`, so only the functions associated with those numbers are allowed. [Read all about it in the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysrq.html).

If you convert `438` to base 2 (`110110110`) it is even easier to see.

```
1     1     0    1    1    0   1   1   0
^256  ^128  ^64  ^32  ^16  ^8  ^4  ^2  ^1
```

Depending on your distribution, you may be able to tell if the kernel was compiled with `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` using this command:

```
$ grep SYSRQ /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

This works for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ah, it's just a linear combination of the individual bitmasks. Thanks very much.

Comment: One follow-up: If nothing happens when I do Alt+SysRq+(a command key), then I suppose this means that sysrq was not enabled when the kernel was installed. Is there a simple way to check whether sysrq is enabled or not (e.g., can I find the status of `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ` somewhere)?

Comment: I added a possible way to check for `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ`.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me on Debian as well. The output: `CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ=y`
`CONFIG_MAGIC_SYSRQ_DEFAULT_MASK=0x01b6` (01b6 in hex is 438 in decimal). I suppose the `y` means it has been enabled. Would give 2 up-votes if I could.

Comment: On many Linux distros, the configuration is kept in the kernel itself, not in `/boot`, so the check command would be **`zgrep SYSRQ /proc/config.gz`** (or `gunzip -c /proc/config.gz | grep SYSRQ`).

Comment: Thanks @grawity. There is no file `/proc/config.gz` on my system, however.

Comment: I did say 'many', not 'all' -- Debian/Ubuntu do keep it in `/boot`.

Comment: **systemd-specific note:** be sure to put the `kernel.sysrq` sysctl into a config `/etc/sysctl.d/51-sysrq.conf` with the prefix **51 or higher**. That's because of `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf` — where they set `kernel.sysrq = 16` (sic!). Check the priorities with `sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysctl --cat-config`; reapply with `sudo systemctl restart systemd-sysctl.service`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Bash one-liner which will print you the enabled options:

```
for i in $(seq 1 8); do (( ($(</proc/sys/kernel/sysrq) & $((1<<$i))) > 0 )) && echo $((1<<$i)); done
```

---

> Which SysRq functions are allowed/disallowed when the bitmask is set to 438?

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 8); do (( (438 & $((1<<$i))) > 0 )) && echo $((1<<$i)); done
2
4
16
32
128
256
```

For the meaning, refer to [William's answer](https://superuser.com/a/375820/87805).

---

To enable all options, run:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

To make it persistent, run:

```
echo kernel.sysrq=1 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/20-sysrq.conf
```

Comment: For persistent config, I had to use something like `60-sysrq.conf` because in case of `20-sysrq.conf`, it was getting overriden by `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/50-default.conf`.

Comment: I wonder why anyone would decide to load the *defaults* at such a late index as 50 rather than at, say, 1. It obviously renders half of the index space useless.