# What is is the bitmask for these SysRq commands?

Tags: linux, hotkeys, sysrq

I for the life of me still can't wrap my mind around bitmasks. I am sure they are very simple, I just haven't found something that makes how they work click in my brain yet.

What would be the bitmask value that I need to put into `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` to only allow these SysRq commands? *✓* represents enabled command, *X* represents disabled commands:

```
✓  r - 4=0x4   - Puts the keyboard into raw mode
✓  k - 4=0x4   - Kills all programs on the current virtual console
✓  s - 16=0x10  - Flushes data from your cache to disk
X  u - 32=0x20  - Remounts all file systems read-only
X  e - 64=0x40  - Sends the terminate signal to all processes
X  i - 64=0x40  - Sends the kill signal to all processes
X  b - 128=0x80 - Reboots your computer
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://superuser.com/a/375820/57822

Comment: Yes, I saw that. The binary part threw me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add the values that you want to be active. However, bitmask values are supposed to be unique. So I guess the value of r & k switch should be different. According to this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/375820/57822), 4 deals with keyboard controls, instead of kill all program. Assuming that all you need is r & s switch, you want the 4+16=20 value